# Matlab - Using special characters in table header

Tags: matlab

I have constructed a table with data from a struct and now wish to add custom headers to the columns before exporting the table. I found the following command:

```
T.Properties.VariableNames{'OldHeader'} = 'NewHeader';
```

This command however does not allow me to use spaces or special characters for my headers. My table contains the output from processed lab data and I wish to have headers like "Vol. [mL]" and "Conc. [wt%]".

To illustrate using the example from [matlab documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2table.html):

```
S.Name = {'CLARK';'BROWN';'MARTIN'};
S.Gender = {'M';'F';'M'};
S.SystolicBP = [124;122;130];
S.DiastolicBP = [93;80;92];
T = struct2table(S)
T.Properties.VariableNames{'Gender'} = 'Sex';
```

The above works, but restricts me to normal characters and no spaces. My question is how to change "Gender" to "Vol. [mL]" - if even possible?

Comment: Matlab variable names have the form `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`. In other words, a valid variable name consists of a letter followed by any number  (within limits) of letters, digits and underscores. `Vol. [mL]` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jubobs already mentioned in the comment, there are some rules for naming variables that prevent you from choosing the exact name that you want. From [the documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html) that I found by googling the topic:

> A valid variable name starts with a letter, followed by letters,
>   digits, or underscores. MATLAB® is case sensitive, so A and a are not
>   the same variable. The maximum length of a variable name is the value
>   that the namelengthmax command returns.
>
> You cannot define variables with the same names as MATLAB keywords,
>   such as if or end. For a complete list, run the iskeyword command.

However, I could think of two easy ways to work around this:

1. Different names, for example you can use the variable name `Vol_ml`
2. Store the names in a list, perhaps with an index code like `v1` for the first variable name, then you can make `v1` the name of the first variable.

Comment: The exported data is to be printed. As such, I was hoping to have the headers be descriptive and without using an index list. Is there no workaround method?

I've tried to set up the data in a cell array but having trouble exporting the data due to the limitations of csvwrite

I just wanted the data out somhow to either a .csv or .xls file

Comment: @user2927919 If you just want to create a file, go for option 2. Perhaps like so: First print the list of relevant headers to the file, then the relevant data.