# How to Create Matlab Tables with Symbols in the Title and Missing Blank Elements

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-table

I am wondering if it is possible to generate a "pretty" table like the one shown below?  So far, it seems that generating tables and then displaying them using table() and uitable() is a bit clunky.  My questions: (1) Can you create column headers that contain symbols and letters such as the infinity symbol or Greek letters?  (2) Is it possible to display an empty cell in a table like what is shown?

[image: Pretty Table]

If Matlab is simply not the way to go to create a table like this, what are some suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab - Using special characters in table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932986/matlab-using-special-characters-in-table-header)

Comment: @YuvalHarpaz Unfortunately it does not.  There they explain that Matlab requires that the headers be formatted as valid variable names.  Special characters, symbols, and greek letters cannot be used as such.