# How to include "@" into a column header when saving as text in Matlab (R2017b)

Tags: matlab

I have a data (*.txt) file with column headers which I have to do some processing on and save the post processed file. It is simple except I am having a problem which I haven't tackled before.

Two of the column headers have "@" which Matlab replaces with "_" when loaded with readtable (filename).

After post processing I would like to have @ back where it was originally (on two column headers) when I save again as a text file (using writetable).

How to implement this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab - Using special characters in table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932986/matlab-using-special-characters-in-table-header)

Answer (score 1):

#### R2017b

I do not know of a good way to accomplish this in R2017b, since table headers are not allowed to contain special characters in R2017b. One option would be to replace the table header names with a special ID like `__AT__` before writing, then do a text replace command like: `sed 's/__AT__/@/g' MyTable.txt`

#### R2019b and after

I think this usability issue was common enough that it was eventually supported by tables in MATLAB.

Use `"VariableNamingRule", "preserve"` to preserve variable names in table headers:

```matlab
% Print the contents of my text table:
>> type MyTable.txt

@Name1 Name2
1 2

% load my table, preserve names
>> MyTable2=readtable("MyTable.txt", "VariableNamingRule", "preserve")

MyTable2 =

  1×2 table

    @Name1    Name2
    ______    _____

      1         2  

% Write names to file
>> writetable(MyTable2);

% Show the contents of the written file:
>> type MyTable2.txt

@Name1,Name2
1,2
```

Comment: From the documentation it seems that the property was named `'PreserveVariableNames'` in R2019b. The doc starts calling it `'VariableNamingRule'` since R2020b. (It is the last bullet of `Input Argument` »`Text and Spreadsheet Files` » `Name-Value Pair Arguments` in the doc of `readtable`)

Comment: @GleasonK Thanks, but I only R2017b to work with. I do not understand your comment on replace text (sed 's/__AT__/@/g' MyTable.txt) and it does not seem efficient. I was wondering if  Encoding with UTF-8 could be used when using readtable ('myfile.txt') as here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html (not working for me yet).

Comment: @jam_27 `sed` is for Linux just to be clear. You can call it inside MATLAB with `system`. Regarding `writetable`, if you want to implement it in R2017b then read the [doc of R2017b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/matlab/ref/writetable.html). You are reading the doc of the latest version instead. That functionality doesn't exist in R2017b